# How to check for Vertex Matching in ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb, graph-traversal

I have created two collections in ArangoDB, a document collection "Node" and an edge collection "Path". All my nodes have a name attribute and are connected by edges.

My traversal has a variable depth of 1..10, which will find the followings paths:

```
start - decide
start - decide - execute1
start - decide - execute2
start - decide - execute1 - error
start - decide - execute2 - end
start - decide - execute1 - execute2 - end
start - decide - execute1 - execute2 - error
start - decide - execute2 - execute3 - end
```

I tried below query to find paths that end with an end or error node:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..10 OUTBOUND 'Node/start_0' Path     
OPTIONS { bfs: true}     
FILTER (v.name == "end" OR v.name == "error")     
RETURN CONCAT_SEPARATOR(' - ', p.vertices[*].name)
```

It gives me below 4 Results

```
[
    start - decide - execute1 - error
    start - decide - execute2 - end
    start - decide - execute1 - execute2 - end
    start - decide - execute1 - execute2 - error
    start - decide - execute2 - execute3 - end
]
```

Here i want to do a additional pattern matching check, I want to list results that has particular sequence of vertex in them.

I want to list the result that has sequence `decide execute1 execute2` in them
i.e., My result should be as given below:

```
     [
     start - decide - execute1 - execute2 - end
     start - decide - execute1 - execute2 - error 
     ]
```

I tried adding below filter condition to my query but it didnot work

```
FILTER LIKE(p.vertices[*].name, "%decide - execute1 - execute2%", true)
```

Can Someone help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work if you move the main query into a subquery, and then apply the filter afterwards, e.g. something like:

```
FOR path IN (
    FOR v, e, p IN 1..10 OUTBOUND 'Node/start_0' Path     
    OPTIONS { bfs: true}     
    FILTER (v.name == "end" OR v.name == "error")     
    RETURN CONCAT_SEPARATOR(' - ', p.vertices[*].name)
)
FILTER LIKE(path, "%decide - execute1 - execute2%", true)
RETURN path
```